# Streetviewevent in Google Maps JavaScript API V3 not found

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I need two events in the Google Maps JavaScript API V3 but i can't find them. First I need the event where the normal map changes to streetview. Secondly the event where the streetview closes. I would really appreciate if you could help me

Best Regards

Thomy

Answer (score 1):

I think for the first one you can use the **visible_changed** event.

The event that's fired when street view closes is **closeclick**

you can check everything in more detail here:

http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#StreetViewPanorama